# Pass Excel data to C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I am looking to pass information from an excel workbook into a C# application that is already open by the user.

Currently, we have an excel workbook with a list of procedure reviews which are summarised as values. For example, a pass is a 1, a minor is 0 and a fail is -1.

This is listed in a sheet with two columns, the name of the procedure and the pass value;

| Procedure  |       Value

|------------|------------

| Test 1     |           1

| Test 2     |           0

| Test 3     |          -1

I would like to take this table and pass it to our reporting application so that it can be manipulated in the front-end and then sent to a database.

Is there any way to create a pipe that will allow for the data to be passed tot he C# application, such as when a button is clicked?

Comment: You could try interop for example. Or there might be better ways depending on the exact circumstances.

Comment: @ADyson I would have done it via a database connection, however the database is protected behind the firewall which refuses connections from unauthorised sources and there is no way to get IT services to allow that connection. 

We have to manually enter the results from the excel workbook to our reporting aplpication, and it would be nice to be able to just click a VBA button and transfer the information over, if it's not possible, then I can just use C# to open the workbook and grab the data itself, but i'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: You can't control the c# from Excel, but you can do it the other way round. if the c# app has its own database or file store you could insert the data there from Excel, and then the c# app would have to know to go and collect it. If there's s firewall in the way though, maybe you could host a web API as an intermediary, or something like that? There are lots of possible solutions to the problem, it's difficult to know what to suggest without full knowledge of the scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application _excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                    _excelApp.Visible = false;
                    string fileName = String.Empty;
                    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
                    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        fileName = ofd.FileName;



                    //open the workbook
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    //select the first sheet or tell it the name of the sheet you want        
                    if ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Worksheet") == null)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid workbook");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item("Worksheet");  
//select how you want data to be transferred into your c# application?
                        tTag.Text = worksheet.get_Range("B2", System.Reflection.Missing.Value).Text;


                        //clean up stuffs
                        workbook.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);

                        _excelApp.Quit();
                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_excelApp);
                    }
                    }
```